# How can I list and count unique words in mysql text columns?

Tags: mysql

This is probably a stupid question with an easy answer but ideally I'd like to be able to get a tally of every unique word and how many times that word occurs across 3 columns.

For example if I have a blog and store plain text of the blog contents in one column, comments in another, and notes in a third and I want to see the top 10 most used words across all 3 of those columns how could I go about doing that?

Comment: You've only tagged this with [tag:mysql]. Does that imply you want a pure MySQL solution? There's no native `split()` or `explode()` function in MySQL, so getting a word list from a column is going to be fiddly.

Comment: i was planning on using php to display it, i was just hoping there was a simple mysql solution for this, though it sounds like that's not the case. i'll have to think about another fiddly way to accomplish what i'm trying to do. thanks!

Comment: a) there is not going to be a simple solution to this.  b) It would be a little easier if you gave some details about your database environment and structure, and maybe a MCVE* c) I gave a theoretical answer, but it would still require a fair bit of implementation from you, as you encounter specific problems d) * information on MCVE: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not a good solution for this.  You can achieve this with JSON functions as of 5.6, I think, but it's a little tricky until 8.0, when mySQL added the JSON_TABLE function, which can convert json data to a table like object and perform selects on it.

```
CREATE TABLE t(raw varchar(100));
INSERT INTO t (raw) VALUES ('this is a test');
```

You will need to strip the symbols (commas, periods, maybe others) from your text, then replace any white text with ",", then wrap the whole thing in [" and "] to json format it.  I'm not going to give a full featured example, because you know better than I do what your data looks like, but something like this (in its simplest form):

```
SELECT CONCAT('["', REPLACE(raw, ' ', '","'), '"]') FROM t;
```

With JSON_TABLE, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT('["', REPLACE(raw, ' ', '","'), '"]') INTO @delimited FROM t;

SELECT * 
FROM JSON_TABLE(
    @delimited,
    "$[*]"
    COLUMNS(Value varchar(50) PATH "$")
) d;
```

See this fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7a86fcc77408ff5dfec7a805c6e4117a

At this point you have a table of the split words, and you can replace `SELECT *` with whatever counting query you want, probably `SELECT Value, count(*) as vol`.  You will also need to use group_concat to handle multiple rows.  Like this:

```
insert into t (raw) values ('this is also a test'), ('and you can test it');

select concat(
    '["', 
    replace(group_concat(raw SEPARATOR '","'), ' ', '","'), 
    '"]'
) into @delimited from t;

SELECT Value, count(*) as vol
FROM JSON_TABLE(
  @delimited,
  "$[*]"
  COLUMNS(Value varchar(50) PATH "$")
) d
GROUP BY Value ORDER BY count(*) DESC;
```

If you are running <8.0, you can still accomplish this, but it will take some hackiness, like generating an arbitrary list of numbers and constructing the paths dynamically from that.